# How to print line number around error in Try-Catch block

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling, try-catch

My script has several try-catch block which sends email about the error message. It works but only one simple line of error message is sent. What I want is the line number around the error and more descriptive messages to help me identify where the error is happening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this (I stole it somewhere), the first converts all info in the catched exception into a string. The second function can be used to wrap some code and if it throws an excetopn write it somewhere.

```
function catchToString (err) {
  var errInfo = "Catched something:\n"; 
  for (var prop in err)  {  
    errInfo += "  property: "+ prop+ "\n    value: ["+ err[prop]+ "]\n"; 
  } 
  errInfo += "  toString(): " + " value: [" + err.toString() + "]"; 
  return errInfo;
}
function catched (f) {
  try {
    f ();
  }
  catch(err) { 
    Logger.log (catchToString (err));
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, if you only want the stack-trace, use `err["stack"]`

Answer (score 0):

The solution above did not work for me, and I found this article:
https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/whereami

The simplest code snippet to test it is:

```
function testError() {
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById('Boooo');  
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err.stack);
  }
}
```

You will log this info:

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.
at testError (#Triggers:164:20)
at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
```

Line of code (164), file (#Triggers) and function name (testError) is here.

I've also tried this library (https://github.com/RomainVialard/ErrorHandler) but now looked for a simpler solution.